# How to emulate ip address

Tags: ip-address

I'm trying to debug the web application that I have made. The errors only show up when I access the system outside the network. When I use something like `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.246:8080/myapp` on my computer it works without errors. 
But when somebody from outside my home network tries to access it errors show up.
So what I want to do now is to be able to emulate being outside by own home network. I have 2 computers 1 desktop and 1 laptop. I'm thinking of using one of them as server and the other will try to access.
Is there any other way of doing this except asking others to test my work from outside?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used [tor](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) for this sort of thing before, or any other sort of proxy - for example [tunnelbear](http://www.tunnelbear.com/). If its a web page/server you can also use a web based proxy site like [daveproxy](http://www.daveproxy.co.uk/) just to see if it connects.

Comment: +1 for tor. You might also get away with just accessing the public ip of your router.

Comment: tried the public ip but no luck I still can't see the errors:)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the proxy method suggested by Journeyman Geek, another way to test is to have two separate Internet connections in your home or office. I have two separate ADSL connections but a cheaper way of performing the occasional test is to tether an Android (or equivalent) mobile phone to your laptop and use it's (3G or other) data connection as an independent Internet access path.

Comment: I do this these days, though its either ADSL or cable for me. I used to use operator (which is something like tor browser bundle) when i had to show people, remotely, the reason they couldn't access $website was local to them ;p